# C++ - Factors of an integer displayed in pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm, factors

I have the code that displays the factors of an inputted integer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int value;
    cout << "Enter a value ";
    cin >> value;

    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        if(value % i == 0) {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

which displays

```
1 2 3 6
```

if the input is `6`.

However, I am not too sure how to get the result as

```
2,3||1,6||
```

Can anyone provide any hints on how I can achieve this?

---

My professor is just going over MOD so I am not sure if this requires a topic that hasn't been covered yet.

Comment: SO is really not for "hints", it's for complete answers, usually using full capabilities of the language, which might not be best for your learning... Still, as a hint... once you find a divisor, then you can divide the orignal with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code as follows :

```
for (int i=1;i<=sqrt(value);i++){
        if(value%i==0){
        cout<<i<<","<<value/i;
    }
```

Include `<math.h>` for `sqrt()`

Or you could use `i * i <= value`

Comment: why does the condition have to be i<=sqrt(value)? I see that if i leave it as i<=value, it also gives me the same pairs but in the reverse order.

Comment: Hi @julianc, this is to avoid duplicate entries. If you loop till `i` equals `value` you will get duplicate entries eg.( [2,3] and [3,2]). Square root of `value` would be the pair[x,y] such that `x == y` after that for any pair [x,y], `x` would be greater than `sqrt(value)` and `y` would be lesser. So `y` will be a value which was already covered. Also when `value` is a high value this approach saves you a lot of unnecessary iterations.

Comment: better to do `i*i<=value`

Answer (score -1):

Store these results in an Array.
Perform another operation on the elements in that array to find out the pairs whose product is equal to the given input.

For example : Store 1, 2, 3, 6 in an array
Perform operations on these elements
1*6 == 6 || 2*3 == 6
Display these pairs.